# How to get the keys from an array sorted from highest to lowest value in php?

Tags: php, sorting

I have an array for example

`$pointsTotal = array('70','23','555','8789','1245');`

I need to sort get the keys from this array from higest to lowest. That means the output in this example should be

`array('4','5','3','1','2')`

Please help.

Comment: The elements in your $pointsTotal array are strings, not integers, right?

Comment: Sorry, they are numbers.`$pointsTotal = array(70,23,555,8789,1245);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this code will solve your problem:

```
<?php    
$pointsTotal = array(70,23,555,8789,1245);
arsort($pointsTotal);
$newArrForKey = array();
foreach($pointsTotal AS $key => $val){
    $newArrForKey[] = $key + 1;
}
print_r($newArrForKey);
```

And the output of above code is:

```
Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 5 [2] => 3 [3] => 1 [4] => 2 )
```

Comment: This also solved my problem. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: @prasanthprem you are welcome. Glad that helped you. :)

Comment: This solution is incorrect and does not retain the proper key val. please see below.

Comment: Why you think its incorrect? I added +1 with each key to fullfill @prasanthprem requirement. Did you check the question???

Comment: @cpugourou bro please read the question carefully before making any comments. And if possible give me an upvote. Thnx

Comment: Yes , you are right ! My bad... sorry about that. It s just that I dont understand his logic . Doing so is going to be messy in case he needs to use the original array again... I upvote of course.

Comment: edit a bit your answer so that I can upvote again. Also, see my one line solution that is quiet different from yours but is a more proper way to do it in class and oop. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

make array from 1 to 5 and sort it synchronously with main array. Keep in mind that main array will be sorted too. Make a copy to save it, if needed

```
$k= range(1, count($pointsTotal));
array_multisort( $pointsTotal, SORT_DESC, $k);

print_r($k);
```

result

```
[ 4, 5, 3, 1,2 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ..

```
 $output= ksort($pointsTotal);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need the keys of the highest to lowest values in this array and the output should be the key's array.

Answer (score 0):

The below code should solve your problem.

```
<?php

$pointsTotal = array('70','23','555','8789','1245');

// Copy pointsTotal, as rsort will modify it

$rsortedPointsTotal = $pointsTotal;

rsort($rsortedPointsTotal);

$pointsIndices = array();

$currentIndex = 0;

foreach($rsortedPointsTotal as $point) {
  $pointsIndices[$currentIndex] = array_search($point, $pointsTotal) + 1;
  $currentIndex++;
}

echo "\n";

foreach ($pointsIndices as $index) {
  echo $index."\n";
}

?>
```

Steps:-

1. First, we copy the original array
2. We then use `rsort()` to reverse sort this copied array.
3. For each index of this reverse sorted array, we find its index in the original array.
4. Taadaa! Done.

Answer (score 0):

William Francis Gomes answer is correct but uses a loop and for dense arrays that could be a problem for efficiency, beside, in class and oop this will kills you.

Here is a one line pure C solution without loop that will works in any cases :

```
arsort($pointsTotal);
$result = array_keys(array_flip(array_map(function($el){ return $el + 1; }, array_flip($pointsTotal))));
```

result

```
Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 5 [2] => 3 [3] => 1 [4] => 2 )
```

In case you want to retain the original keys:

```
arsort($pointsTotal);
$result = array_values(array_flip($pointsTotal));
```

result:

```
Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 [2] => 2 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 )
```